# can't push eclipse repository to GitHub anymore

Tags: git, eclipse, github, repository, push

I'm currently a CS student and am working on a private project to get some experience. Now everything worked fine with git and eclipse and pushing and synchronizing was no problem. But from one minute to another it just stopped working.

I don't get any error messages and eclipse is never complaining, but Git does't get the changes in the repository. Can you help me please?

Here is the latest entry to the log file, in case this is part of the problem.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2021-02-20 13:25:05.015
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Jan'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
```

```
$ git push
To https://github.com/ComputersCalculateFast/Hexapawn.git
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/ComputersCalculateFast/Hexapawn.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

After pulling, like Git Bash suggested I get the message the other way around

```
$ git push
To https://github.com/ComputersCalculateFast/Hexapawn.git
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/ComputersCalculateFast/Hexapawn.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a message there. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail.

Comment: What do you mean with it doesn't get the changes?

Comment: @dan1st
When I change my code in eclipse and push it to GitHub, my GitHub repository will not get any changes. The weird thing is, that it used to work and then from one minute to another it stopped.

Comment: Does it work using the CLI?

Comment: @dan1st 
wow, you are fast. I never used the CLI, I downloaded Git CMD, but I need to look up how to use it. Do you have any suggestion what I should try, or where I can look up the information I need?

Comment: You can use the command `git push <remote name> <branch name>` (e.g. `git push origin master`). Make sure to do it in the correct directory.

Comment: @dan1st
I'm completely new to GitHub, besides having created a repository and synchronized my local eclipse workspace to it, so I need some more details.

With <remote name> do you mean the eclipse workspace folder for this project?

Comment: The remote is the url of the github repository or an abbreviation. By default, the abbreviation is `origin`. The branch name is the name of the branch you want to push (`master` or `main` by default).

Comment: @dan1st Ok, I'm still not exactly sure. I don't find the repository in my eclipse workspace, like all my "normal" Java projects. But If you look at the error message in my OG post, it says something about my default location to store repositories is C: \Users\Username. I think thats what I need, but I read about people pushing their entire C-drive to GitHub so i would like someone to confirm haha

I found the folder, do I use only 'C:\Users\Jan' or 'C:\Users\Jan\git\projecName'?

Comment: It would fail before pushing the C drive as there are limits. However, if you only work in the repository you want to push, you will only push that repository.

Comment: @dan1st I get the error message you can see in my OG post in the CLI when I try to push. I don't know why the remote repository should be ahead of my local repository. Only thing I can imagine is the README.md but I already edited the local file to be replaced by the one on my remote repository.

Comment: If you make the same changes on both sides, those will be treated as different changes. You can try to add `-f` in that case in order to overwrite the changes on GitHub.

Comment: @dan1st It worked!!! Thank you!

Comment: Can you push from eclipse, now?

Comment: @dan1st Yes, i tested it. It works just fine again

Comment: @dan1st one thing to note, maybe. The README was listed in the unstaged changes bar in eclipse. That wasn't the case before I used the ```-f```

Comment: Unstaged means you have changed the file without (yet) telling git to keep track of that change.